# Understanding example on VaR

Tags: value-at-risk

Trying to understand [the example below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk) on VaR in Wikipedia. I don't really understand how the 1% VaR is being defined here. Firstly, shouldn't it be 1% Var is 100 since its the amount her looses? And secondly, I dont understand this statement: "the probability that he loses less than zero (which is impossible) is less than 99%.". Given 1% Var = -100 as per their definition shouldnt it be "the probability that he loses less than -100 is less than 99%." and not 0?

> More formally, p VaR is defined such that the probability of a loss
>   greater than VaR is less than or equal to p while the probability of a
>   loss less than VaR is less than or equal to 1−p. For instance, assume
>   someone makes a bet that flipping a coin seven times will not give
>   seven heads. The terms are that he gains 100 if it doesn't happen
>   (with probability 127/128) but loses $12,700 if it does (with
>   probability 1/128). The 1% VaR is then -100, because the probability
>   that he loses more than that is less than 1% while the probability
>   that he loses less than zero (which is impossible) is less than 99%.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood it is as follows:

- If you **DO NOT** get 7 heads out of seven flips, then you make 100\$;
- If you **DO** get 7 heads out of seven flips, then you lose 12 700\$;

The probability of **NOT** getting seven heads is $\frac{127}{128} = 99,21875\%$ and $1-p = 0.78125\%$. Therefore, with 99% confidence level VaR you are still making 100\$ (I think that's why there is a minus sign). Since VaR ignores tail events, you are not losing at 99% VaR. Hence the statement:

> ... the probability that you lose **MORE** than -100\$ is less than 1%, while the probability that he loses **LESS** than zero (which is impossible) is less than 99%.

Maybe taking a look at the [original statement](https://www.tilsonfunds.com/Einhorn-4-08.pdf)  by Einhorn may be helpful:

[image]